# Mysql json type default sort issue

Tags: mysql, json

If we insert/update json data to Mysql json type, it always sort by default.

For example, if we insert `{"b": "Toyota", "a": "Volvo", "c": "BMW"}` it always storing as `{"a": "Volvo", "b": "Toyota", "c": "BMW"}`

Any idea to store as it is.

Thanks

Comment: `The normalization performed by MySQL also sorts the keys of a JSON object (for the purpose of making lookups more efficient). The result of this ordering is subject to change and not guaranteed to be consistent across releases. In addition, extra whitespace between keys, values, or elements in the original document is discarded.`, see [11.6 The JSON Data Type::Normalization, Merging, and Autowrapping of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-normalization).

Answer (score 0):

To make lookups more efficient, it also sorts the keys of a JSON object. You should be aware that the result of this ordering is subject to change and not guaranteed to be consistent across releases.

The solution is to convert the column type to 'text' then the order of keys will not be changed!